# Modal popup extender not displaying popup

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have inherited some code using an ASP modal popup extender and for some reason it has now decided to stop working. Am I missing anything here? I'm not too fluent with AJAX / ASP.Net right now so im struggling to diagnose what is going wrong here.

So firstly the javascript method that displays the modal

```
 function ShowModalRemoveEvent(ID, EventID, InstructorID, InstructorName)
      {
         alert("Hi");
         var modal = $find('ModalPopupExtender1');
         modal.show();
         document.getElementById("txtID").value = ID;
         document.getElementById("txtEventID").value = EventID;
         document.getElementById("txtInstructorID").value = InstructorID;
         document.getElementById("txtInstructorName").value = InstructorName;
      }
```

I know this is being called because of the alert. So I would assume the prpblem is either in finding the ModalPopupExtender1 or the modal.show() line.

Here is the code for my modal popup extender

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="ModalBackground">
            <table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tr>
                  <td width="7%" class="cellAlertHeader">
                     <img src="../../../images/Ops/window_delete.png" style="width: 18px; height: 18px" alt=""/>
                  </td>
                  <td width="93%" class="cellAlertHeader">
                     <b>Cancel Instructor Event</b>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;<td width="95%">
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" Style="display: none" runat="server" CssClass="TextboxTitle"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEventID" Style="display: none" runat="server" CssClass="TextboxTitle"></asp:TextBox>
                     </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtInstructorID" Style="display: none" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"
                        CssClass="TextboxTitle"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtInstructorName" Style="font-size: 12px" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"
                        CssClass="TextboxTitle" BorderWidth="0"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Are you sure you want to remove this Event?"
                        CssClass="TextboxTitle"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     <asp:Button ID="ButtonConfirmRemove" runat="server" Text="Confirm" CssClass="buttonshort" />
                     <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="buttonshort" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="5%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
                  <td width="95%">
                     &nbsp;
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </asp:Panel>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="dummyButton" Style="display: none" />
         <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
                                 runat="server" 
                                 PopupControlID="Panel4"
                                 TargetControlID="dummyButton" 
                                 BackgroundCssClass="ModalBGOpacity" 
                                 CancelControlID="ButtonCancel"
                                 OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()">
         </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dummyButton" />
      </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Maybe you add a library like jQuery/prototype and the symbol $ change the way of working.

Comment: @Aristos Good idea, I've checked the master page and we dont have any libraries included other than the javascript file for the modal popup

Comment: the second issue here is to check how modal id is rendered on html code. Is ModalPopupExtender1 or other way and you need to add ModalPopupExtender1.CliendID to get the rendered id. If you add this code on master page client then this id has change now

Comment: @Aristos Thanks a lot this was exactly the problem.  If you want to answer the question I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the rendered id of your control, like that.

```
 var modal = $find('<%=ModalPopupExtender1.CliendID%>');
```